# CSS DIV WRAPPER

Tags: css, html

Well I've been trying for a couple of days now to center the content inside a wrapping `div`. Inside this `div` I have 3 other `div`s, one beside the other with margins and images.
I did most of the code searching on these forums (congratz for me) knowing just about nothing about coding.

Anyways...

Here's the code, if anyone could help me out would be great!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://puente-aereo.net/clientes/perceptualweb/perceptual/ndxz-studio/imgs/perceptual.ico">

<meta name="keywords" content="perceptual, bench, perceptualstudio, diseño, mobiliario, interiores">

<meta name="description" content="Perceptual, Perceptual Studio, Bench">

<meta name="author" content="puente-aereo.net">

<title>Perceptual, Perceptual Studio, Bench</title>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">

.container {
    width: 1333px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.spancol {
    width: 250px;
}
.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
p {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #666;
    word-wrap: normal;
    word-break: break-all;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div align="center" class="container">

<div class="column spancol"><p>.................................................................................................................................................................................................................. ...... ..................... Marca de mobiliario / furniture brand .... .......................................................................................................
</p><a href="#"><img src="http://puente-aereo.net/clientes/perceptualweb/perceptual_hd.jpg"/></a>
<p>.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................. diseñado y fabricado en Colombia / designed and manufactured in Colombia............................................................................................................................................................................ lineas simples /simple lines ............................ ...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................funcionalidad/ functionality................ .......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................atencion a los detalles / attention to details .... ...................................................................................................................... diseños atemporales / timeless design ................... ........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................</p>
</div>

<div class="column spancol"><p>................................................................................................................................Estudio de diseño / design studio ......... ....................................................................</p><a href="#"><img src="http://puente-aereo.net/clientes/perceptualweb/perceptualstudio_hd.jpg"/></a>
<p>......................................................................................................................................................................... diseño comercial / commercial design ........................... ..................................................................................................................................................................................................................... .....diseño de producto / product design ................... .................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................diseño corp  rativo / corporate design ................ ................................. ...............................................................................................................................................................................................................diseño residencial /residential design..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................</p>
</div>

<div class="column spancol last"><p>..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................fabricante de mobiliario/furniture manufacturing .................................. ................................... ..................................</p><a href="#"><img src="http://puente-aereo.net/clientes/perceptualweb/bench_hd.jpg"/></a>
<p>..................................................................... .......mobiliario  arquitectonico / architectural furniture ........... ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................ desarrollo de mobiliario personalizado/custom furniture developement ........... ....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floated div is causing     .conatainer to have no height.

http://jsfiddle.net/6zS7D/

You can add in your container:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: Omg!!! This worked!!! I'm seeing I was missing a text-align parametter???

Comment: Thx GUYS!!! This works great for me!
It's like real-time help over here THX!!!THX!!!THX!!!

Comment: Uhmmm Andrew...
Is there a way I can make those divs spread the width of the screen with equal spaces between them and on the side of the columns?
I tried usign width: 100%; on the container but it gets all messed up...

Comment: @restre http://jsfiddle.net/UvEVB/ Like this?

Comment: OMG! Yes just like that!!!
Now I've been practicing with that a lot, just trying to learn that from memory and movign things around to learn more!
Thank you so very much!